# Ciar uma galeria e colocar em um ScrollView

Tags: android

Estou usando isto para utilizar como uma galeria de imagens .

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/galeria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

mais não esta funcionando quando eu coloco dentro de um ScrollView

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o meu layout, o texto não cabe todo na tela em alguns momentos ai preciso de um ScrollView ,queria colocar a galeria dentro dele para subir a foto e o texto , eu só consegui colocar no texto ai não fica muito bom porque algumas pessoas não vão tentar subir só o texto

Estou adicionando as imagens assim 
aki no main

```
ViewPager galeria = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.galeria);
    GaleriaImagensAdapter adapter = null;
    try {
        adapter = new GaleriaImagensAdapter(this, packageName, id);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    galeria.setAdapter(adapter);
```

e o adapter

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, int position) {
    ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
    imagem.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    try {
        String nome_foto = itens.get(position).nome_foto;
        int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nome_foto, "drawable", packageName);

        imagem.setImageResource(drawableId);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
    }
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(imagem, 0);
    return imagem;
}
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com não está funcionando? Ele não está passando entre os itens? Como você está adicionando as imagens em seu `ViewPager`? Se puder postar um trecho de código seria ótimo

Comment: tipo do jeito que está funciona normal , mais não tenho um scroll na tela toda, ai quando eu coloco dentro do scroll ele some, não aparece mais